# unhandled page fault (11) at 0x0000000c, code 0x017

Tags: android, c, android-asynctask

I am trying to start a native app from within an android app (Android Jelly bean (4.1.2)). I am able to start the native app manually from adb, however it does not start from android. The native app is inside **AsyncTask** and it is started by the **doInBackground** function. The command I use to start the app inside android is:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/MyAppDir/CAL_Android > /data/data/MyAppDir/out.txt 2>&1 &");
```

I simplified the command as below, but still did not start:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/MyAppDir/CAL_Android");
```

My various attempts at debugging the issue:

1. Start a simple command, like "touch file.txt" from android. Works
2. Moved the native app to /data/local/tmp. Did not work.
3. Changed the execute permission to 777 (rwxrwxrwx). Did not work.
4. Changed the owner to root apart from that of the app. Did not work.
5. Tried using a thread (**implements Runnable** instead of **extends AsyncTask**). Did not work.
6. Execute command using "su -c" ("su -c /data/data/MyAppDir/CAL_Android"). Did not work.
7. Place the command to execute inside a shell script and invoke shell script from Android. Did not work.

I checked the dmesg output and the error I get is:

```
<7>[14156.022980] CAL_Android: unhandled page fault (11) at 0x0000000c, code 0x017
<1>[14156.023010] pgd = e6204000
<1>[14156.026306] [0000000c] *pgd=b0728831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
<4>[14156.032777] 
<4>[14156.034242] Pid: 9408, comm:          CAL_Android
<4>[14156.051821] CPU: 0    Tainted: G        W     (3.4.0-ge11b2fc-dirty #1)
<4>[14156.061557] PC is at 0x4012aa22
```

Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

**EDIT:**
The dmesg output is not correct. After checking a few more times, I am not getting the error message in dmesg. The crash seems to have happened due to a different unknown reason. But I have added an answer to the reason for not being able to start the native app from android. Hopefully this helps someone who faces a similar issue.

Comment: apparently your cal application crashes

Comment: Is it because, the address space is different when apps are started from Android and when started from adb? The native app when started by android, is not able to access certain memory locations?

Comment: i don't know, mostly because i have no idea what your application is trying to do.

Comment: The native app, sends and receives packets. It writes the time at which the packets were sent to a file (/data/data/MyAppDir). It also writes the time at which it received a packet from another node and the MAC address to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the android app was not able to start the native app, by using the below 2 lines and printing them in the log.

```
BufferedReader std_input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader std_error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

String line;
while ((line = std_error.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.i(TAG, line);
}
```

When I used "su -c" before my command, I got this error message:

```
su: uid <xyz> not allowed to su
```

and when I did not use "su -c" I got this one instead:

```
"Cannot open socket: Operation not permitted"
```

The reason is that, the android app does not have root permission to start the native app and the native app needs root permission to open a socket for sending and receiving data.